# how to simulate right click in javascript

Tags: javascript, right-click

Ok, so i know i can simulate a click by running this code

```
document.getElementById('recover').click();
```

the closest this i could find was cntextmenu so i tried

```
document.getElementById('recover').contextmenu();
```

however this does nothing

Is it possible to right click and element to bring up the contextual menu so i can click an item on that list ? and if so could someone point me in the correct direction to accomplish such a goal ?

I've done some searching but the only thing i have found is jquery javascript capturing of the event not actually triggering the event

Comment: I'd say it's better to use a custom menu so you can have a much better control over it.

Comment: Is it a custom context menu or the browser's?

Comment: You can't open the default browser context menu. You can hijack that and make your own though.

Comment: the duplicate question that i somehow failed to find works for for me now i just have to figure out which element to click :)

Comment: This answer was good for me, but I wanted to simulate a click at the current mouse position. So where the code says 0,0,0,0, I replaced the last two 0's with the current mouse x/y position relative to the screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

with jQuery

```
$('#recover').trigger({
    type: 'mousedown',
    which: 3
});
```

otherwise

```
var element = document.getElementById('recover');
var e = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');

e.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true,
     element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
     false, false, false,2, null);


return !element.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use the jQuery trigger() functionality.

```
$('#recover').trigger({
    type: 'mousedown',
    which: 3
});
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may wish to trigger a mouse down and then a mouse up, which could go like this:

```
$('#recover').trigger({
    type: 'mousedown',
    which: 3
}).trigger({
    type: 'mouseup',
    which: 3
});
```

I'm not a big fan of chaining long commands like that, but whatever is most readable for your app is fine.

Comment: Excellent, a downvote for a working solution. Well done anonymous chap.

Comment: Why doesn't this demo work?
http://jsbin.com/OjubeKU/1/edit

Comment: What makes you think it's not working, @andreaconsole? You don't have any logging to prove it to a human, but the computer is probably working fine. What did you expect it to do? Also, you should create a new question probably.

Comment: you are right, Jordan, I expected to see the context menu, but I found that this will not happen, even if I didn't understand exactly why...

Comment: This does not work. Can you remove it?